# Вопрос по JavaScript. textContent или что то другое?

Tags: javascript

Не получается реализовать следующий код. Не понимаю почему. tel.textContent - возвращает undefined.
Хотя если получать доступ к элементу через  getElementsById('tel'), то всё работает.

```
var tel = document.getElementsByClassName('tel');
var str = tel.textContent;
for (var i = 0; i < tel.length; i++){
    tel[i].setAttribute('href', 'tel:' + str);
}
```

Comment: Но мне нужна коллекция элементов, поэтому нужен доступ через классы

Answer (score 1):

```
var tel = document.getElementsByClassName('tel');
for (var i = 0; i < tel.length; i++){
  var str = tel[i].textContent;
  tel[i].setAttribute('href', 'tel:' + str);
}
```